# Maven plugin that runs a "web proxy" for integration tests

Tags: java, maven, proxy, integration-testing

This might be confusing, so bear with me.

I am not interested in running maven behind a proxy. I understand how to configure maven, eclipse or the JVM itself to get web access via proxies.

However, in my project, I have a component that will retrieve the contents of a given URL and analyze it. It uses Apache Http Components underneath, coated with a little predefined configuration and error handling (really just a wrapper to hide boiler plate code). Since apache-httpcomponents itself can make use of proxies, my component will accept a proxy configuration that can be passed to apache-httpcomponents.

Does anyone know of any proxy plugin that allows this type of integration test, like "maven-simpleproxy-plugin" or anything like that?

I want to test the ability of my component to run well behind a proxy. I imagine that I would need to run some sort of plugin which will start up a dummy proxy server along with maven-embedded-glassfish-plugin. I can host a dummy content inside glassfish and make my component try to access it via this "maven-simpleproxy-plugin" instance... thus allowing me to test the component's ability to handle its proxy configuration correctly.

Does anything like that exist?

Answer (score 1):

I would use [maven exec](http://mojo.codehaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/) plugin to start up the proxy server you want to test. Then write a script which is called at the `post-integration-test` phase that shuts the proxy server down. Then you are testing through the same proxy server type as your production environment.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Just waiting a few days to see if anyone else has any other suggestions, but I'll likely mark this as the official answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for [MockServer](http://www.mock-server.com/). It looks pretty active on github with 1.000+ stars and 25+ contributors and can do the following, as explained on their website:

> **MockServer Proxy can:**
>
> - proxy all requests using any of the following proxying methods:
>
>   - Port Forwarding
>   - Web Proxying (i.e. HTTP proxy)
>   - HTTPS Tunneling Proxying (using HTTP CONNECT)
>   - SOCKS Proxying (i.e. dynamic port forwarding)
> - verify requests have been sent (i.e. in a test assertion)
> - record requests and responses to analyse how a system behaves

Regarding the different deployment/usage options you've been asking for, let me again copy from their website:

> **The MockServer and MockServer Proxy can be run:**
>
> - via a Maven Plugin as part of a Maven build cycle
> - programmatically via a Java API in an @Before or @After method
> - using a JUnit @Rule via a @Rule annotated field in a JUnit test
> - from the command line as a stand-alone process in a test environment
> - as a deployable WAR to an existing application server
> - as a Grunt plugin as part of a Grunt build cycle
> - as a Node.js (npm) module from any Node.js code
> - as a Docker container in any Docker enabled environment

ps: I'm not affiliated in any way with the project